# Cannot Connect to SQS with Akka-Camel

Tags: scala, apache-camel, akka, amazon-sqs

I'm trying to push messages through my Scala application to an SQS queue. I receive the following error when trying to connect to SQS:

```
ProducerRegistrar$$anonfun$receive$3.applyOrElse(CamelSupervisor.scala:159)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:425)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:386)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:230)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:212)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$MailboxExecutionTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:506)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: aws-sqs://analyticsSandboxSQS?accessKey=<access>&secretKey=<secret> due to: No component found with scheme: aws-sqs
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:475)
    at akka.camel.internal.ProducerRegistrar$$anonfun$receive$3.applyOrElse(CamelSupervisor.scala:151)
    ... 9 more
```

I have used the following code to setup the URI:

```
import akka.actor.{ Actor, ActorSystem, Props }
import akka.camel.{ Oneway, Producer }

class EventSenderSQS extends Actor with Producer with Oneway {
  def endpointUri = "aws-sqs://queueName?accessKey=<access>&secretKey=<secret>"
}
```

And I use the following to try to send a message:

```
val sys = ActorSystem("sys")
val eventsActor = sys.actorOf(Props[EventProducerSQS])
eventsActor ! "testMessage"
```

I am using akka-camel version 2.1.4, which should support the aws-sqs endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace shows you need to put the camel-aws jar and aws-sdk jars into the class path.

Comment: That worked! More specifically, these are the SBT dependencies that I added:
    "org.apache.camel" % "camel-aws" % "2.12.2","com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.0.002"